# How will circular DMA periph to memory behave at the end of the transfer in STM32?

Tags: embedded, usb, stm32, spi, dma

I wanted to ask, how will behave DMA SPI rx in STM32 in following situation.
I have a specified (for example) 96 Bytes array called A which is intended to store the data received from the SPI. I turn on my circular SPI DMA which operates on each Byte, is configured to 96 Byte.
Is it possible, when DMA will fill my 96 Bytes array, the Transfer Complete interrupt will went off, to quickly copy the 96 Byte array to another - B, before circular DMA will start writing to A(and destroy the data saved in B)?
I want to transfer(every time when I will get new data from A in B) data from B quickly over USB to PC.

I'm just thinking how to transmit continous data stream SPI from STM32 over USB to PC, because a block of 96 Bytes of data transferred by USB once per certain time is easier I think than stream in real time SPI to USB by STM32? I don't know it's even possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible, it is a race.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that to work, you would have to be able to guarantee that you can copy all the data before the next SPI byte is received and transferred to the start of the buffer.  Whether that were possible would depend on the clock speed of the processor and the speed of the SPI, and be able to guarantee that no higher priority interrupts occur that might delay the transfer.  To be safe it would need an exceptionally slow SPI speed, and in that case would probably not need to use DMA at all.

All in all it is a bad idea and entirely unnecessary. The DMA controller has a "half-transfer" interrupt for exactly this purpose.  You will get the HT interrupt when the first 48 bytes are transferred, and the DMA will continue transferring the remaining 48 bytes while you copy *lower half* buffer.  When you get the transfer complete you transfer the *upper half*.  That extends the time you have to transfer the data from the receive time of a single byte to the receive time of 48 bytes.

If you actually need 96 bytes on each transfer, then you simply make your buffer 192 bytes long (2 x 96).

In pseudo-code:

```
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 96
char DMA_Buffer[2][BUFFER_LENGTH] ;

void DMA_IRQHandler()
{
    if( DMA_IT_Flag(DMA_HT) == SET )
    {
        memcpy( B, DMA_Buffer[0], BUFFER_LENGTH ) ;
        Clear_IT_Flag(DMA_HT) ;
    }
    else if( DMA_IT_Flag(DMA_TC) == SET )
    {
        memcpy( B, DMA_Buffer[1], BUFFER_LENGTH ) ;
        Clear_IT_Flag(DMA_TC) ;
    }
}
```

With respect to transferring the data to a PC over USB, first of all you need to be sure that your USB transfer rate is at least as fast or faster than the SPI transfer rate.  It is likely that the USB transfer is less deterministic (because it is controlled by the PC host - that is you can only output data on the USB when the host explicitly asks for it), so even if the the *average* transfer rate is sufficient, there may be latency that requires further buffering, so rather then simply copying from the DMA buffer A to a USB buffer B, you may need a circular buffer or FIFO queue to feed the USB.  On the other hand, if you already have the buffer `DMA_Buffer[0]`, `DMA_Buffer[1]` and `B` you already effectively have a FIFO of three blocks of 96 bytes, which may be sufficient

Comment: Nice! I got Your idea. But what is the variable name which i have to set in dma ? is it just "DMA_Buffer"?

Comment: I just forgot, what if my device which sends SPI data will stop sending?
Will i have an interrupt that it stopped?

Comment: @Niko : Regarding the address of the DMA buffer, yes DMA_Buffer is valid (cast to uint32_t) - all data in an array is contiguous, so it points to a block of 192 bytes, the use of a 2 dimensional array is just to simplify the code.

Comment: @Niko : Regarding failure to complete a transfer, you will have to implement some kind of timeout - you should really post a new question for that, but essentially you start/restart a timer on every HT/TC interrupt. If the timer interrupt occurs before the  the DMA interrupt, that data stream has stalled.  You might then grab the partial buffer and restart the DMA, or leave the DMA running, and keep a note of how much you have taken, so that when the next DMA interrupt does occur, you only take the remainder not previously read.

Comment: @Niko :  Further on the timeout issue, it is only relevant of you are the slave SPI device. If you are the SPI master, then the data will not "stop" unless you as master stop the SPI - even if the slave is not actively updating its shift-out, the master will clock and shift in whatever level is on the MISO line - which will be a delayed copy of whatever it sent.

Comment: And if the stm32 is just the spi slave? When it will notice the CS is going high, does it will stop the dma?

Comment: @Niko I am standing my ground now, this is not the way SO works.  It is Q&A not a conversation, and in any case you are likely to get a better answer that is of more use to the community in general by posting a new question to the community rather than asking extension questions in comments to an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 3):

In one of my projects I faced a similar problem. The task was to transfer data coming from an external ADC chip (connected with SPI) to PC over full speed USB. The data was (8 ch x 16-bit) and I was requested to achieve the fastest sampling frequency possible.

I ended up with a **triple buffer** solution. There is 4 possible states a buffer can be in:

1. **READY:** Buffer is full with data, ready to be send over USB
2. **SENT:** Buffer is already sent and outdated
3. **IN_USE:** DMA (requested by SPI) is currently filling this buffer
4. **NEXT:** This buffer is considered empty and will be used when IN_USE is full.

As the timing of the USB request can't be synchonized with with the SPI process, I believe a double buffer solution wouldn't work. If you don't have a *NEXT* buffer, by the time you decide to send the *READY* buffer, DMA may finish filling the *IN_USE* buffer and start corrupting the *READY* buffer. But in a triple buffer solution, *READY* buffer is safe to send over USB, as it won't be filled even the current *IN_USE* buffer is full.

So the buffer states look like this as the time passes:

```
Buf0     Buf1      Buf2
====     ====      ====
READY    IN_USE    NEXT
SENT     IN_USE    NEXT
NEXT     READY     IN_USE
NEXT     SENT      IN_USE
IN_USE   NEXT      READY
```

Of course, if the PC don't start USB requests fast enough, you may still loose a *READY* buffer as soon as it turns into *NEXT* (before becoming *SENT*). PC sends USB IN requests asynchronously with no info about the current buffer states. If there is no *READY* buffer (it's in *SENT* state), the STM32 responds with a ZLP (zero length package) and the PC tries again after 1 ms delay.

For the implementation on STM32, I use double buffered mode and I modify M0AR & M1AR registers in the *DMA Transfer Complete* ISR to address 3 buffers.

BTW, I used (3 x 4000) bytes buffers and achieved 32 kHz sampling frequency at the end. USB is configured as vendor specific class and it uses bulk transfers.

Answer (score 3):

Generally using circular DMA only works if you trigger on the half full/half empty, otherwise you don't have enough time to copy information out of the buffer.

I would recommend against copying the data out the buffer during the interrupt. Rather use the data directly from the buffer without an additional copy step.

If you do the copy in the interrupt, you are blocking other lower priority interrupts during the copy. On a STM32 a simple naive byte copy of 48 bytes may take  additional 48*6 ~ 300 clock cycles.

If you track the buffers read and write positions independently, you just need to update a single pointer and post a delayed a notification call to the consumer of the buffer.

If you want a longer period then don't use circular DMA, rather use normal DMA in 48 byte blocks and implement circular byte buffer as a data structure.

I did this for a USART at 460k baud that receives asynchronously variable length packets. If you ensure that the producer only updates the write pointer and the consumer only updates the read pointer you can avoid data races in most of it. Note that the read and write of an aligned <=32 bit variable on cortex m3/m4 is atomic.

The included code is a simplified version of the circular buffer with DMA support that I used. It is limited to buffer sizes that are 2^n and uses Templates and C++11 functionality so it may not be suitable depending on your development/platform constraints.

To use the buffer call getDmaReadBlock()  or getDMAwriteBlock() and get the DMA memory address and block length. Once the DMA completes use skipRead() / skipWrite() to increment the read or write pointers by the actual amount that was transferred.

```
 /**
   * Creates a circular buffer. There is a read pointer and a write pointer
   * The buffer is full when the write pointer is = read pointer -1
   */
 template<uint16_t SIZE=256>
  class CircularByteBuffer {
    public:
      struct MemBlock {
          uint8_t  *blockStart;
          uint16_t blockLength;
      };

    private:
      uint8_t *_data;
      uint16_t _readIndex;
      uint16_t _writeIndex;

      static constexpr uint16_t _mask = SIZE - 1;

      // is the circular buffer a power of 2
      static_assert((SIZE & (SIZE - 1)) == 0);

    public:
      CircularByteBuffer &operator=(const CircularByteBuffer &) = default;

      CircularByteBuffer(uint8_t (&data)[SIZE]);

      CircularByteBuffer(const CircularByteBuffer &) = default;

      ~CircularByteBuffer() = default;

    private:
      static uint16_t wrapIndex(int32_t index);

    public:
      /*
       * The number of byte available to be read. Writing bytes to the buffer can only increase this amount.
       */
      uint16_t readBytesAvail() const;

      /**
       * Return the number of bytes that can still be written. Reading bytes can only increase this amount.
       */
      uint16_t writeBytesAvail() const;

      /**
       * Read a byte from the buffer and increment the read pointer
       */
      uint8_t readByte();

      /**
       * Write a byte to the buffer and increment the write pointer. Throws away the byte if there is no space left.
       * @param byte
       */
      void writeByte(uint8_t byte);

      /**
       * Provide read only access to the buffer without incrementing the pointer. Whilst memory accesses outside the
       * allocated memeory can be performed. Garbage data can still be read if that byte does not contain valid data
       * @param pos the offset from teh current read pointer
       * @return the byte at the given offset in the buffer.
       */
      uint8_t operator[](uint32_t pos) const;

      /**
       * INcrement the read pointer by a given amount
       */
      void skipRead(uint16_t amount);
      /**
       * Increment the read pointer by a given amount
       */
      void skipWrite(uint16_t amount);


      /**
       * Get the start and lenght of the memeory block used for DMA writes into the queue.
       * @return
       */
      MemBlock getDmaWriteBlock();

      /**
       * Get the start and lenght of the memeory block used for DMA reads from the queue.
       * @return
       */
      MemBlock getDmaReadBlock();

  };

  // CircularByteBuffer
  // ------------------
  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::CircularByteBuffer(uint8_t (&data)[SIZE]):
      _data(data),
      _readIndex(0),
      _writeIndex(0) {
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline uint16_t CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::wrapIndex(int32_t index){
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(index & _mask);
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline uint16_t CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::readBytesAvail() const {
    return wrapIndex(_writeIndex - _readIndex);
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline uint16_t CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::writeBytesAvail() const {
    return wrapIndex(_readIndex - _writeIndex - 1);
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline uint8_t CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::readByte() {
    if (readBytesAvail()) {
      uint8_t result = _data[_readIndex];
      _readIndex = wrapIndex(_readIndex+1);
      return result;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline void CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::writeByte(uint8_t byte) {
    if (writeBytesAvail()) {
      _data[_writeIndex] = byte;
      _writeIndex = wrapIndex(_writeIndex+1);
    }
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline uint8_t CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::operator[](uint32_t pos) const {
    return _data[wrapIndex(_readIndex + pos)];
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline void CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::skipRead(uint16_t amount) {
    _readIndex = wrapIndex(_readIndex+ amount);
  }

  template<uint16_t SIZE>
  inline void CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::skipWrite(uint16_t amount) {
    _writeIndex = wrapIndex(_writeIndex+ amount);
  }

  template <uint16_t SIZE>
  inline typename CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::MemBlock  CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::getDmaWriteBlock(){
    uint16_t len = static_cast<uint16_t>(SIZE - _writeIndex);
   // full is  (write == (read -1)) so on wrap around we need to ensure that we stop 1 off from the read pointer.
    if( _readIndex == 0){
      len = static_cast<uint16_t>(len - 1);
    }
    if( _readIndex > _writeIndex){
      len = static_cast<uint16_t>(_readIndex - _writeIndex - 1);
    }
    return {&_data[_writeIndex], len};
  }

  template <uint16_t SIZE>
  inline typename CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::MemBlock  CircularByteBuffer<SIZE>::getDmaReadBlock(){
    if( _readIndex > _writeIndex){
      return {&_data[_readIndex], static_cast<uint16_t>(SIZE- _readIndex)};
    } else {
      return {&_data[_readIndex], static_cast<uint16_t>(_writeIndex - _readIndex)};
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: reviving an old answer, but how do you efficiently use DMA while receiving variable width packets? TX is easy as you set the transfer length but for RX you don't know what'll be coming in, so you're either using an transfer length of a byte or using some kind of timeout mechanism, aren't you?

Comment: For the STM32  uarts, they implement a character timeout interrupt., which is what you want rather then a general timeout. The interrupt fires x bit intervals after receiving the last character with no more in the process of being received. So either the DMA fires an interrupt or the character timeout interrupt fires and you need to check the status of the DMA and transfer out what is there.

Comment: For variable width packets you may check CNDTR, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71048068/14157403