# HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback() circular DMA: What address is the data?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32f3

I'm using the HAL with an STM32F3xx, implementing UART receive with **circular DMA**. The data should continually be received into the `huart->pRxBuffPtr` buffer, overwriting old data as new data arrives, and the `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback()` function gets called regularly to copy out the data before it gets overwritten. The `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback()` function receives a `size` parameter and of course a pointer `huart`, but no direct indication of where in the `huart->pRxBuffPtr` the freshly arrived data was DMA'd to.

How do I know whereabouts in `huart->pRxBuffPtr` the freshly arrived data starts?

Comment: Look at the DMA stream data number register (called NDTR or something like that) it counts down the number of items remaining and then gets reset to the count of items when the buffer wraps.  Subtract the value you initially wrote from the current value to get the number of items stored.  Obviously this number is out of date as soon as you read it, but the DMA will only be accessing items after where it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to Tom V for the hint. For future generations, here is the solution code - a function which returns true and gets the next available byte, otherwise returns false:

```
bool uart_receiveByte(uint8_t *pData) {
  static size_t dmaTail = 0u;

  bool isByteReceived = false;

  // dmaHead is the next position in the buffer the DMA will write to.
  // dmaTail is the next position in the buffer to be read from.
  const size_t dmaHead = huart->RxXferSize - huart->hdmarx->Instance->CNDTR;

  if (dmaTail != dmaHead) {
    isByteReceived = true;
    *pData = pRxDmaBuffer[dmaTail];
    if (++dmaTail >= huart->RxXferSize) {
      dmaTail = 0u;
    }
  }

  return isByteReceived;
}
```